# Threadsafe readonly property

Tags: ios, thread-safety, readonly

i have a parent class `Networking` and two child `Upload : Networking` and `Download : Networking`. The Networking has public `@property (readonly) BOOL isExecuting;` and `@property (readonly) BOOL isDone;`. I need to access them from within the child classes, but in a thread-safe way, as the operations will go in separate threads.

What is a elegant way to implement it? Thanks!

Edit: so do i get it correctly? This is an example of Upload.m

```
#import "Upload.h"
#import "Networking.h"

@interface Upload ()

@property (assign) BOOL isExecuting;

@end

@implementation Upload

- (void) setIsExecuting:(BOOL)isExecuting{
    @synchronized (self) {
        _isExecuting = isExecuting;
    }
}
```

Comment: My gut reaction is `@synchronized(self)`.

Answer (score 0):

As your property is readonly, no thread will go on to change its value. So in any of the thread any time, you will get same value.

Therefore no need to worry about that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Anoop, but uploading and downloading may do at the same time, and on separate threads. So, here is an example of Upload.m, did i get it correctly?